# Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When you call the library to upload controller, an error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65488 bytes) in
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Symfony\web\system\core\Log.php on line 478

Controller method edit:

```
 function edit($id){
  $this->action ="edit";
  if (empty($_POST["id"])) $_POST["id"]  = $id;
  if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
   $_POST['image'] = $this->model_img_upload->imageUpload($this->imUploadConfig);
   if($this->model_akcii->edit_data($_POST)){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',$this->lang->line('msg_edit'));
    redirect('akcii');
   }
  }
  $this->item = $this->model_akcii->get_info($id);
  $this->item_lang = $this->model_akcii->get_lang_info($id);
  $this->load->view("edit",$this);
 }
```

imageUpload method:

```
function imageUpload ($config=array()){
  if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){
  $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $this->transliterate($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   $config['upload_path'] = isset($config['upload_path'])?$config['upload_path']:$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/userfiles/images/' ;
   if (!file_exists($config['upload_path']))
    if (phpversion() >= 5) mkdir($config['upload_path'],0755,true); else {
     $paths = split("/",$config['upload_path']); $makepath="";
     foreach ($paths as $p){ $makepath .=$p."/"; if (!file_exists($makepath)) mkdir($makepath,0755); }
    }
   $config['allowed_types'] = isset($config['allowed_types'])?$config['allowed_types']:'jpg|gif|png' ;
   $config['max_size'] = isset($config['max_size'])?$config['max_size']:'1000' ;
   $config['max_width'] = isset($config['max_width'])?$config['max_width']:'2048' ;
   $config['max_height'] = isset($config['max_height'])?$config['max_height']:'2048' ;
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    return false;
   } else  {
    $imgdata = $this->upload->data();
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2' ;
    $config['source_image'] = $imgdata['full_path'];
    $config['quality'] = isset($config['quality'])?$config['quality']:"100%" ;
    $config['create_thumb'] = isset($config['create_thumb'])?$config['create_thumb']:TRUE ;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = isset($config['maintain_ratio'])?$config['maintain_ratio']:TRUE ;
    $config['width'] = isset($config['width'])?$config['width']:140 ;
    $config['height'] = isset($config['height'])?$config['height']:115 ;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    return $imgdata['file_name'];
   }
  }
```

This error appeared after the upgrade engine to codeigniter 3.

```
memory_limit = 1G
```

Comment: There is probably a infinite (recursive?) loop, increasing the memory limit may not solve the problem.

Comment: Even if the cause just $ this-> load-> library ('upload', $ config); in any controller will still hang